# How to set the body background image at 50%?

Tags: html, css

How can I make the body image only visible in half? 
I also tried with background-size, I don't succeed or I don't realize being a beginner.
Looking for a few good hours to answer the question, I do not realize how I can make the image to be seen only half of the screen.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PfsL.jpg]

```css
body {
  background: url(bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  margin-top: -10px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.vertical-nav {
 min-width: 17rem;
 width: 17rem;
   height: 100vh;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 transition: all 0.4s;
}

.page-content {
  width: calc(100% - 17rem);
  margin-left: 17rem;
  transition: all 0.4s;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Startup</title>

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS from a CDN. This way you don't have to include the bootstrap file yourself -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!-- Your own stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="vertical-nav bg-white" id="sidebar">
      <p class="text-gray font-weight-bold text-uppercase px-3 small pb-4 mb-0">BAZA DE DATE</p>
     <ul class="nav flex-column mb-0">
      <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link text-dark font-italic bg-light" href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-home mr-3 text-primary fa-fw"></i>
            Acasa
          </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link text-dark font-italic bg-light" href="#">Active</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link text-dark font-italic bg-light" href="#">Active</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="page-content p-5" id="content">
      <h2 class="display-4 text-white">Bootstrap vertical nav</h2>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you try `background-size:auto 50%` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

div::after {
  content: "";
  background: url(image.jpg);
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;   
}
```

There is no CSS property background-opacity, but you can fake it by inserting a pseudo element with regular opacity the exact size of the element behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code where I was able to achieve it.

```css
.main{
  overflow: hidden;
}

.div1{
  width:30%;
  height:400px;
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
}

.div2{
  width:70%;
  height:400px;
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.cusImg{
  width:100%;
  height:100% 
}

.topLeft{
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Startup</title>

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS from a CDN. This way you don't have to include the bootstrap file yourself -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!-- Your own stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="main">
  <div class="vertical-nav bg-white div1" id="sidebar">
      <p class="text-gray font-weight-bold text-uppercase px-3 small pb-4 mb-0">BAZA DE DATE</p>
     <ul class="nav flex-column mb-0">
      <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link text-dark font-italic bg-light" href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-home mr-3 text-primary fa-fw"></i>
            Acasa
          </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link text-dark font-italic bg-light" href="#">Active</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link text-dark font-italic bg-light" href="#">Active</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
  <div class="div2">
 <img class="cusImg" src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4005/4706825697_c0367e6dee_b.jpg" alt="">
 <div class="topLeft">
 Hello There!
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html
```

Let me know if this helps you.